# OpenAM Insert Card Login Page

Tags: java, openam

OpenAM is protecting an application with "certificate only" restrictions.
If I try to access it without a card with a certificate, OpenAM will display an Authentication Error. 
How can I make it show a notice asking to insert card with a certificate instead of the error?

Open application -> Display notice asking to insert card -> Insert Card, click OK -> Authentication Module

Thanks

Comment: cert-based auth actually happens at the SSL/TLS layer (client auth). OpenAM does not / can not detect where the keypair resides, software token or smartcard. If the secure listener of the container mandates client auth the error happens way down the protcol stack.

You could try to adjust 'login_failed_template.jsp' for the OpenAM auth chain to fit your needs (see docs)

Comment: Thanks. Any way to tell login_failed_template whether the authentication method is certificate, user/pass or any other?

Comment: if you use service based auth you can customized the template files independently, you may have a look at http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/install-guide/index.html#update-classic-ui